# SQL: Count of rows before and after given row

Tags: sql

The problem is that we are to get total number of rows before and after a given row (identified by, say, primary key).

I have tried following in T-SQL (MSSQL 2008). It is giving right result, but I don't know if this is best way to do it.

```
;WITH cte_before AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Order By CustomerId ) [Row Number], customerid, 
           firstName 
    FROM SalesLT.Customer
 ),
cte_nums AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Order By CustomerId ) [Row Number1] 
    FROM SalesLT.Customer
)
SELECT [Row Number]-1 [before], MAX([Row Number1]) - [Row Number]
       , CustomerID, FirstName 
FROM cte_nums, cte_before
GROUP BY [Row Number], CustomerID, FirstName
HAVING CustomerID = 55
```

How can we improve it in T-SQL and how can we accomplish in other SQL dialects and server (like Oracle, MySQL, sqlite, FireBird etc.)

Comment: That statement wil never run with any other DBMS due to the non-standard usage of the `[` quote characters. If you either avoid column names that need quoting or use the standard `"` characters, the above statement will run in Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2 (and the upcoming Firebird 3.0 as it will support windowing functions as well)

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name (it will be better if you get a name) this is only for t-sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work in any dialect:

```
select 
   (select count(*) from SalesLT.Customer where customerid < 55) as rows_before,
   (select count(*) from SalesLT.Customer where customerid > 55) as rows_after,
   CustomerID, FirstName
from SalesLT.Customer
where CustomerID = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as Philip's, but implemented properly and tested.  This uses only stock standard ANSI SQL.

```
SELECT A.customerid, A.firstName,
  count(case when B.customerid < A.customerid then 1 end) count_before,
  count(case when B.customerid > A.customerid then 1 end) count_after
FROM SalesLT.Customer A
cross join SalesLT.Customer B
where A.customerID=55
GROUP BY A.customerid, A.firstName
```

The "A" alias finds the customer you want (55).  The join to B produces one row for each customer, for which each row is tested for A.customerID.

The CASE clause produces

- 1 ; when the condition < A.customerid[55] is met
- null (implicit without an ELSE clause) when not met
- `Count` skips null values, so the total comes out right

GROUP BY is required to use COUNT(), an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

An improved SQL version:

```
DECLARE @CustomerId int

SET @CustomerId = 55

SELECT
   @CustomerId
  ,ThisOne.FirstName
  ,sum(case when Agg.CustomerId < @CustomerId then 1 else 0 end)  [Before]
  ,sum(case when Agg.CustomerId > @CustomerId then 1 else 0 end)  [After]
 from SalesLT.Customer Agg
  inner join SalesLT.Customer ThisOne
   on ThisOne.CustomerId = @CustomerId
```

Comment: You are missing the `group by`. What is the purpose of the self join?

Comment: The join was to retrieve the FirstName for the specified CustomerId (since that was part of the original result set). As for executing or not, what is the error message? I did and do not have a data set that I can test the code against for syntax errors.