# Putting SQL COUNT result into a php variable

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, count

The issue I'm having is hopefully fairly simple, but I've been darting around various different solutions for a couple of days with no luck. I have a php script that's doing several different things to return a set of results, and what's working so far is that I can get a player's name, yield hit score along with the 5 above and 4 below him.

To explain my problem, visualise that the active player's score is the 432nd highest score, instead of showing the scores as 1., 2., 3. and so on, I need to display 432 next to his score, 431 for the one above and so on.

I was planning on doing this by running a COUNT query that checks how many score are above the player (to get his place in the list, then replacing making my $i variable used for listen the position of the score become $i = $resultfromcount - 4, so that it'll show the correct scoreboard position for each score shown. I'm having problems with getting $i to store the right thing though, following several different theoretical solutions hasn't worked. With some I'm getting the error related to 'accessing a member function in a non-object', or with others $i is simply empty.

Here's my code (some of it is irrelevant but I figured it best to show the entirety of the script) stripped of the different solutions I've tried, the one you see below is simply returning null for $i:

```
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$DB_NAME = 'mydb';
$DB_HOST = 'myhost';
$DB_USER = 'myuser';
$DB_PASS = 'mypass';


$name = ($_GET['name']);


$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Querying the several queries needed and combining them
$allquery = "SELECT *
             FROM `scores`";


$scoreresult = "SELECT `score` 
                FROM `scores` 
                WHERE `name` = '$name'";

$userscorequery = " SELECT * FROM 
                   (
                        (
                        SELECT * FROM
                        (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM `scores`
                            WHERE `score` >= ($scoreresult) ORDER BY `score` ASC LIMIT 5

                        ) `finalResult` ORDER BY `score` DESC
                        )
                        UNION ALL
                        (
                        SELECT * FROM
                        (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM `scores`
                            WHERE `score` < ($scoreresult) ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5

                        ) `secondFinal` ORDER BY `score` ASC
                        )

                    ) `nearScores` ORDER BY `score` DESC";    


$indexing = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   `index`
                    FROM `scores`
                    WHERE `score` > ($scoreresult)";

$indexresult = $mysqli->query($userscorequery) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$result = $mysqli->query($userscorequery) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $ind = $indexresult->fetch_assoc();
    $i = $ind[0];
    echo $i;
} else {
    echo 'NO INDEX';
}

// GOING THROUGH THE DATA
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "$i. \t \t {$row['name']} \t \t \t \t \t {$row['score']}m \n";
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo 'NO RESULTS';  
}

// CLOSE CONNECTION
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: You could likely do it all in the query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159064/sql-rows-before-and-after-given-row

Comment: By that do you mean I could try incorporating it into the main query that's running? I tried doing that at one point actually, but I had trouble and didn't get a result.

Comment: Yes, you could count them that way.

Comment: While it wasn't through this method, I've actually got it working now (I spotted that I had certain queries that weren't running the right things)

But this would have been viable and is probably what I'll advance it to when I get on to optimising, so thanks so much man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I fixed this due to having a simple problem; I was running the $userscore query in the first mysqli run when I should have been running the indexing query! Silly mistake, but we all make them ;o